# Retrieve all directories with file system api

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem

Is there a way to count all directories within a folder with file system api without being stuck in an infinite loop!?

Can't figure out why or where the leak is but I eventually had to quit my app after it got to 50K - it never looked like reaching an end point. I am on OS X so is it counting all the hidden directories and files such as DS Store?

```
//path: my folder
app.workspace.getDirectory(path, {}, function(directory){
    var reader = directory.createReader();
    if(directory){
        reader.readEntries(function(entries){
            for(var i = 0; entries.length; i++) {
                if(entries.isDirectory){
                    console.log('Directory: ', entries[i]);
                }
                else {
                    //don't need to know anything else...
                }
            }
        });
    }
}, error);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop is never checking `i` against `entries.length` when it iterates.

Modify
`for(var i = 0; entries.length; i++)`
to
`for(var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++)`

Additionally, I assume `if(entries.isDirectory)`
should be `if(entries[i].isDirectory)`.

Comment: I couldn't stop laughing! It's been a long day... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [bro-fs](https://github.com/vitalets/bro-fs) that can read directories recursively:

```
fs.readdir('dir', {deep: true})
  .then(tree => console.log(tree))
```